# How to import multiple functions from module into one object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

I want something like this:

```
import {get, set} as moduleName from 'module-name'

moduleName.get()
```

The reason is because sometimes methods of different modules can have the same name, and I don't want to import the whole module because of it

Comment: You can do `import {get as g, set as s} from "module-name"` but `import {get, set} as moduleName from 'module-name'` is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as:

```
import {get, set} as moduleName from 'module-name'
```

You can either do it like this:

```
import * as moduleName from 'module-name';
moduleName.get();  //all the exported items will be accessible.
```

Or this:

```
import {get as moduleNameGet, set as moduleNameSet} from 'module-name';
moduleNameGet();
```

[Please check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax

```
import * as module from "module-name";
```